# File upload field in CCK field settings

Tags: 7, entities, files

Is there a difference in Drupal 7 to add a file-upload field on a "normal" form (i.e. a separate page for a modules' configuration) as opposed to the small settings area for a CCK field (the one that appears after clicking on the cog for the field you'd like to modify under the "Manage Display" tab)?

I have a bunch of configuration options for a custom field using [hook_field_formatter_settings_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field_ui--field_ui.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_settings_form/7), but am stuck at trying to figure out how to create a file upload field. I'd ideally like to have the user able to browse for an image and upload it without having the page reload. This is all I currently have:

```
$element['custom_field_name']['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#size' => 48,
    '#title' => t('Image upload'),
    '#description' => t("Upload an image."),
);
```

If it is possible to have a file upload field (that uses ajax) in this area, what else must I do?

**Edit**:

My file field now looks like this:

```
$element['custom_field_name']['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Image upload'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array(0 => 'png jpg jpeg gif'),
      'file_validate_image_resolution' => array('64x64', '10x10')
    ),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://default_images/',
    '#description' => t("Upload an image."),
);
```

This is sort of working: it allows me to upload a file and it goes to `sites/default/files/default_images`, but its only temporary. I've been going through [the form api reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/) and it says I need to permanently save it. I am just unsure how where to put this logic. Do I add a `#process` key to my file field and call some private function? Or do I create a submit handler? The API reference doesn't go into as much detail as I'd like.

Comment: Drupal 7 already has what you are asking for: it's an image field, which allows you to upload an image on the server, and show it though a field widget.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm not sure if what I just did is what you're talking about, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT` to the status of the file on form submit then save the file.

```
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);
```